# How to map same routes for two controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two controller in my MVC application. One is `Home` controller and other is `User` controller. I am using following RouteConfig settings.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "actiononly",
            "{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I want `abc.com/Blog`
       `abc.com/Login`
Instead of `abc.com/Home/Blog`
       `abc.com/User/Login`.
Above configuration works fine with `abc.com/Blog` but it is not working with `abc.com/Login`.
How to remove controller name from the link for both controllers?
Also how can I only show `abc.com` when website launches instead of `abc.com/index`? I am using following code in my webpage to access the particular page.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Blog", "Home")
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "User")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your default route should automatically cater for wanting to nav to `abc.com` without requiring the `index` part of the URL

You need to ensure that your main route is specified as the default:

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Site_Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{*id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

If you want to map short routes you can do exactly what you've done above. I use this helper function in my own project to map short routes:

```
void ShortRoute(string action, string controller)
{
    ShortRoute(action, controller, action);
}

void ShortRoute(string action, string controller, string route)
{
    _context.MapRoute(route, route, new { action, controller });
}
```

With usage:

```
ShortRoute("About", "Home");
```

Which allows me to navigate to `mywebsite.com/about` instead of `mywebsite.com/home/about`

If it's not working for certain URLs it may be that the route handler is matching a different route - I believe it *does* depend on the order you register them

There's a good route debugging plugin you can use

https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/

It gives you a summary of all routes and which ones matched the current URL - very useful

Comment: Thanks for reply Charleh. Few questions. Where do I add `ShortRoute` method? In RouteConfig file? Also where do I call `ShortRoute("About", "Home")`? I add this helper method in my project than do I have to use this method for all the actions?

Answer (score 1):

Without bringing in additional packages, you simply need to add an additional route.  To create the new route, you first must define what you want your URL to be.  In this case, you have said you want to be able to go to `/Login` which is on the user controller.  Ok - let's create a new route.  This route should be located **ABOVE** your default route.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "UserLogin",
            "Login/{id}",
            new { controller = "User", action="Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

The first parameter is simply the route name.  The second parameter is the format of the URL that I want this route to match.  Given we know what action we want to match to this route, we don't need the `{action}` or `{controller}` catchall placeholders that are in the default route.  Also note that we can declare what controller this route will hit without having to specify the controller in the URL.

Last note, you don't have to have the `{id}` be part of the route if you will never be passing an ID parameter to that function.  If that is the case, then you can safely remove any references to `id` in the UserLogin route.

As I re-read your question, you should be able to do this for some of your other examples as well.  Let's take the `/About` URL and demonstrate the removal of the `{id}` parameter.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "AboutUsPage",
            "About",
            new { controller = "Home", action="About"}
    );
```

Comment: What if I have multiple actions in both controllers? than `Login/{id}` will not be valid for other actions. How do I proceed with that?

Comment: Correct, at some point, you will have the controller name in the route, as the above will get unruly.  I believe you can use wildcard mappings as well.  It really depends on WHY you need your URLs to look the way you want.  Sometimes, the extra work may not really be worth saving four characters in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

This is *very* simple. You just need to create a route for each of your expected URLs.

Keep in mind that if you don't pass the controller or action as a URL placeholder, you will need to do so manually by providing them as default values.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Blog",
        "Blog/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Blog", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
routes.MapRoute(
        "Login",
        "Login/{id}",
        new { controller = "User", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```